# I/O error :The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, networking, oracle-sqldeveloper, listener, tns

[image: error]

Hello, these days I am stuck in trying to establish a connection with oracle database using sql devlopper, although I can easily connect with it using sqlplus.
If anyone here can help me, please don't hesist.

oracle database version: 21c 21.3.0.0.0
sql devlopper:  22.2.1.234.181

Comment: For multitenant database (> 11g), connect through the SERVICE_NAME instead of SID.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried using this method but nothing was happening. I still find the same error.